# .net core - entity framework - [DefaultValue] not working

Tags: .net, entity-framework, enums

I wanted to use the [DefaultValue] annotation on my entity to specify a default value that gets stored in the DB when creating and not setting the value for status.

```
// ApprovalStatus is Enum
// Pending = 2
[DefaultValue(ApprovalStatus.Pending)]
public ApprovalStatus Status { get; set; }
```

But unfortunately the value stored in the DB when creating and saving the entity is 0 and not 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and kind regards,
Nikolai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use the fluent API, data annotations are not supported in this scenario:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Status)
            .HasDefaultValue(ApprovalStatus.Pending);
    }
```

see https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relational/default-values.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this!